# Алгоритм случайного числа

Tags: android, android-ndk, c, c++, алгоритм

В моем проекте используется функция rand() из стандартной библиотеки С. К сожалению, в android-ndk я не нашел подобной функции. Не подскажете алгоритм для ее реализации?

Comment: А разве rand не является чистью libc в android?

Comment: Как оказалось, нет.

Comment: Не верю.

Comment: Интересно, что ничего по данному вопросу не нагуглилось. Т.е. либо, и правда, нет такой функции в Андроидовской libc, либо нет такой проблемы и Вы что-то делаете не так ;).

Answer (score 2):

Что-то у вас там не то. Ну не может быть такого.

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ pwd                      
/home/cy6ergn0m/dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ fgrep -rn "int rand(void)" ./platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include         
./platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:117:static __inline__ int rand(void) {
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ fgrep -rn "int rand(void)" ./platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/include
./platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:116:static __inline__ int rand(void) {
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ fgrep -rn "int rand(void)" ./platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include
./platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:116:static __inline__ int rand(void) {
```

Как видно, функция rand на месте, а если открыть файл на 117й строке, то видно, что и все остальные стандартные функции тоже в добром здравии.

***UPD*** Смотрим нативные либы

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ ./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -d ./platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.so | grep ":$" | grep rand
00017498 <__dorand48>:
00017b5c <jrand48>:
00017c08 <lrand48>:
00017c2c <mrand48>:
00017c50 <nrand48>:
000182f8 <srand48>:
0001f304 <_dorand48>:
0001f52c <arc4random_buf>:
0001f5cc <arc4random>:
0001f62c <arc4random_uniform>:
0001f668 <arc4random_stir>:
0001f708 <arc4random_addrandom>:
0001f98c <drand48>:
0001f9ac <erand48>:
00026710 <__res_randomid>:
00027638 <random_bind>:
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $
```

Как видно, необходимые функции присутствуют, в том числе lrand48, на которую ссылается rand в заголовочнике (rand - инлайн-функция):

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine dist/dev/android-ndk-r5b $ head -n 130 ./platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h | tail -n 15
#define RAND_MAX 0x7fffffff
static __inline__ int rand(void) {
return (int)lrand48();
}
static __inline__ void srand(unsigned int __s) {
srand48(__s);
}
static __inline__ long random(void)
{
return lrand48();
}
static __inline__ void srandom(unsigned int __s)
{
srand48(__s);
}
```

Comment: Может, версия другая? :)

Answer (score 2):

Не должно быть проблем с rand в NDK. Берем пример Hello-JNI из NDK и добавляем туда вызов rand:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    char out[256] = { 0 };

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    sprintf(out, "Rand is = %d", rand() % 10 + 1);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, out);
}
```

И проверяем на эмуляторе:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Взять простейший, но надежный вариант у Кнута. 
Пока не было C++11, я у себя использовал примерно такой генератор - по крайней мере, с диапазоном побольше, чем 2<sup>15</sup> :)

```
class Random
{
public:
    typedef int RandomValue;
    Random& operator = (int seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random(int seed = 1):X(seed){};
    int operator()(int seed = 0)
    {
        const int MM = 2147483647;
        const int AA =      48271;
        const int QQ =      44488;
        const int RR =       3399;
        if (seed != 0) X = seed;
        X = AA*(X%QQ)-RR*(X/QQ);
        if (X < 0) X += MM;
        return X-1;
    }
    int operator()(int min, int max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    int X;
};
```

Метод и константы взяты в "Искусстве программирования" Кнута.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте из `/dev/random` или `/dev/urandom`.

[Вот](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/external/dropbear/random.c) пример кода, так поступающего (правда, там всё намного хитрее). Думаю, разберётесь :).

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм функции rand() основан на линейно-конгруэнтном генераторе, когда из старого числа получается новое. Эта функция работает по следующему алгоритму:

X=A*X+C;

X=>>16;

X&=0x7FFF

Все числа 32-битные (или 64-битные) у каждой фирмы изготовителя коэффициенты A и B свои. Их надо находить. Правило поиска указаны в книге Д.Кнут "Искусство программирования"